# Why does a tsql stored proceedure that calls sp_who return different results when called through SqlCommnad than it does through SSMS?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to write a stored procedure to determine the number of connections on the active database. My stored procedure is currently as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetActiveUsers]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @who TABLE(spid SMALLINT, ecid SMALLINT, [status] NCHAR(30), loginame NCHAR(128), hostname NCHAR(128), blk CHAR(5), dbname NCHAR(128), cmd NCHAR(16), request_id INT);
    INSERT INTO @who
    exec sp_who 'FMApp'
    --SELECT 99,98,'good','person','host','12345','db','1234567890123456',1
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS [ActiveUsers] FROM @who; 
END
```

The reason I am putting the results of sp_who into a table variable is so that I can do some further filtering on the results. I've removed the filtering for now for the sake of debugging.

When I call this stored procedure through SQL Server Management Studio it behaves as expected and I get a non zero value. When I call it through C# using a SqlCommand however it always returns zero.

Calling code:
*Note: connectionService.Create returns an open SqlConnection

```
using (var connection = connectionService.Create())
{
    var activeUsersSql = "GetActiveUsers";

    using (var command = new SqlCommand(activeUsersSql, connection))
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                activeUsers = reader.GetInt32(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I alter my stored procedure to populate my table variable from a source other than sp_who then both the call to SSMS and the call through SqlCommand agree on the result.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetActiveUsers]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @who TABLE(spid SMALLINT, ecid SMALLINT, [status] NCHAR(30), loginame NCHAR(128), hostname NCHAR(128), blk CHAR(5), dbname NCHAR(128), cmd NCHAR(16), request_id INT);
    INSERT INTO @who
    SELECT 99,98,'good','person','host','12345','db','1234567890123456',1
    --exec sp_who 'FMApp'
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS [ActiveUsers] FROM @who; 
END
```

Is it an issues of permissions, a restriction on the use of sp_* procedures or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Does the user you are using to connect in code have the `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission? If not, you won't get much detail from that.

Comment: The user did not have VIEW SERVER STATE permission, however I was using the same user in both SSMS and in my connection string. I have since added that permission and the results remain the same.

Comment: Instead of using Reader can you give it a try with: `var result=command.ExecuteScalar()`

Comment: You need to check the connection string and check what driver (provider) is being used.  Either you are connecting to the wrong database or there is an issue with the driver.  In most cases usually you have two copies of the database and you  are connecting to a different copy of the database.

Comment: @TheMixy Using ExecuteScalar is gives me the same results as ExecuteReader.

Comment: @jdweng I can confirm that I am accessing the same database. When I switch between my two stored procedures via SSMS the change is reflected in my running code. 

With regards to the provider, I don't specify a provider in my connection string as per the example on the SqlConnection class documentation. My understanding is that this will result in the ADO.NET provider being used but I could be wrong. The same connection string is used elsewhere in the application for other queries.

Comment: The default provider is the SQL.Client library in Net.  The syntax is is same in c# and SQL server. You not see any differences if you are using the same database.

Comment: It may be easier to uses the system DMVs: sys.dm_exec_sessions and sys.dm_exec_connections

Comment: Check the ldf log files on server.  I've never seen a case when SSMS and c# returned different results with same database.  On time there is an issue is the parameter lists and you do not have any parameters.  I would use a connection string.  Right now you are probably connecting to a local database with no data.

Comment: @DavidG Hey Dave, it looks like you were right. It was the VIEW SERVER STATE permission after all. I added the permission to the wrong user when I tried initially. Do you want to add an answer so I can mark as accepted?

Comment: I'm constantly fascinated when people call me Dave when I've explicitly said my name is David.

Comment: @DavidG Sorry, force of habit. I've got two Davids in the office that both go by Dave.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @DavidG the issue was one of permissions. Without the VIEW SERVER STATE permission you can only view your own session. The user I was filtering by was different from the one I was running the process as so it always came up as zero.

Answer (score 0):

To view or retrieve results from sp_who/sp_who2 should need VIEW SERVER STATE permission. I you are using administrator account to connect to SQL server via your C# application it should return data. Check the permission assigned with the account that you use to connect to SQL server in your application.

If no permission, user will be able to see only current session.